# How to store data into a collection form string in Blue Prism

Tags: c#, blueprism, rpa

Presently working on Blue Prism V5.0, now i am working with the code block in BP now my aim is to get all the filesnames in a given folder/path. For this I am using the C# code.

```
String[] str = Directory.GetFiles(inputFolderPath);
```

for this I am providing the input file/folder path through the same code block, the output of the file is string by default but BP doesn't have the type String so, how to convert the data type string to a collection.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is standard BluePrism action that does that!

```
Object: Utility - File Management
Action: Get Files
```

It's pretty good, because it does output a lot of columns, including: filename and filepath, extension, size et cetera.

It also allows for filtering the results. Example could be ".*pdf" that should force action to return only the files with that extension.

Answer (score 1):

Add an output to your code stage of Collection (`System.Data.DataTable`) type. Then, convert the `String[]` to a DataTable manually:

```
outputCollection = new DataTable(); // might not be necessary as Blue Prism will generally instantiate the instance for you; remove this line if you're receiving compiler warnings/errors

// create a column to store your paths
DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
col.ColumnName = "Filename";
outputCollection.Columns.Add(col);

// loop through the String[] array and place the values in the DataTable structure
foreach (String el in str) {
    DataRow row = outputCollection.NewRow();
    row["Filename"] = el;
    outputCollection.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

When this is output back to your Blue Prism workflow, you'll have a single column in your output collection of "Text" data type.